# get an Var with an onclick

Tags: javascript, html

I want to make every picture on my website bigger only on onclick event. Sure I can take for every Pic the Java code, but I want sth to open all pics with one command! Thanks

```js
function pic(choice, click){
    p = choice;
    p.style.width = "200px";
}
```

```html
<div onclick="pic('b1')" style="position: absolute; top: 100px; left: 100px; width: 100px; height: 100px; background-color: red;"></div>

<div onclick="pic('b2')" style="position: absolute; top: 100px; left: 500px; width: 100px; height: 100px; background-color: red;"></div>
```

Comment: what is `b1` & `b2`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can send the element calling the `onClick` event by sending `this` in the trigger, like this :

HTML :

```
<div onclick="pic(this)" style="position: absolute; top: 100px; left: 100px; width: 100px; height: 100px; background-color: red;"></div>
```

JS :

```
function pic(element){
  element.style.width = "200px";
}
```

Comment: Oh Thanks a LOT :D

Answer (score 1):

You have to give the reference to the element in order to access that from JS. Try this,

```js
function pic(choice, click){
 p = document.getElementById(choice);
  p.style.width = "200px";
}
```

```html
<div id="b1" onclick="pic('b1')" style="position: absolute; top: 100px; left: 100px; width: 100px; height: 100px; background-color: red;"></div>

<div id="b2" onclick="pic('b2')" style="position: absolute; top: 100px; left: 500px; width: 100px; height: 100px; background-color: red;"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple jQuery example
https://jsfiddle.net/thebeast/0e6yLk2h/

HTML:

```
   <div class="box one"></div>
   <div class="box two"></div>
```

CSS:

```
   .box {
     height: 50px;
     width: 50px;
   }

   .one {
     background-color: red;
   }

   .two {
     background-color: blue;
   }

   .large {
     width: 300px;
     height: 300px;
    }
```

JS:

```
   $('.box').click(function(e) {
      var box = e.target;
      $(box).toggleClass("large");
    })
```